# procedure return does not happen properly

Tags: assembly, call, procedure

I'm using TASM for assembly 8086, I have two files. I call the read procedure from one file and want to use it 3 times in the other file. After the first usage program crashes.

read.asm file:

```
PUBLIC READ
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
BUFFER DB 200 DUP(?)
FLAG DB 0
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
;PUBLIC READ

; read procedure reads a string character by character from the keyboard 
READ PROC FAR
PUSH DS
    XOR AX,AX
    PUSH AX
    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    XOR DI,DI

; readloop is the loop for reading the string character by character
READLOOP:
    MOV AH,01H
    INT 21H; al will get the character
    MOV BUFFER[DI],AL; the character is stored
    INC DI
    CMP AL,0DH
    JNZ READLOOP; the reading continues until the ENTER key is pressed

; we display the string
    MOV AL,0
    MOV BUFFER[DI],24H
    LEA DX,BUFFER
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

; converting the string to a real number
    XOR SI,SI
    XOR DX,DX
    MOV DL,BUFFER[SI]
    XOR AX,AX
    XOR CX,CX

; converter loop converts the string to a real number memorizing where the decimal point was
CONVERTER:
    CMP DL,2EH; searching for the decimal point
    JZ FLOATINGPOINT
    CMP FLAG,1
    JNZ NEXT2
    INC CX; position of the decimal point stored

NEXT2:
    SUB DL,30H; deducing the character which digit is
    PUSH DX; storing the value of dx on the stack
    MOV BX,10
    MUL BX
    POP DX
    ADD AX,DX; retrieving the value as an integer in AX
    JMP NEXT

FLOATINGPOINT:
    MOV FLAG,1

NEXT:
    INC SI
    MOV DL,BUFFER[SI]
    CMP DL,0DH; doing the conversion until the ENTER key is pressed
    JNZ CONVERTER
    RET
READ ENDP

SAMPLE PROC FAR
    RET
SAMPLE ENDP
CODE ENDS
    END SAMPLE
```

main.asm file:

```
GLOBAL READ:FAR
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
SIDEONE DW ?
SIDETWO DW ?
SIDETHREE DW ?
HALFPERIMETER DB ?
DECIMALPOINTONE DB ?
DECIMALPOINTTWO DB ?
DECIMALPOINTTHREE DB ?
MESSAGE1 DB 10,13,10,13,"Please input the length of the first side:$"
MESSAGE2 DB 10,13,"Please input the length of the second side:$"
MESSAGE3 DB 10,13,"Please input the length of the third side:$"
WELCOMEMESSAGE DB "Welcome to my triangle area calculator!$"
CONTINUEMESSAGE DB 10,13,10,13,"Do you want another try? y-yes n-no:$"
RESULTMESSAGE DB 10,13,10,13,"The area of the triangle is:$"
RESULT DB ?
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
MAIN PROC FAR
    PUSH DS
    XOR AX,AX
    PUSH AX
    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV DX,OFFSET WELCOMEMESSAGE
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    XOR DX,DX
    XOR AX,AX

START:
    LEA DX,MESSAGE1
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    XOR DX,DX
    CALL READ
    MOV SIDEONE,AX
    MOV DECIMALPOINTONE,CL
    XOR DX,DX
    XOR AX,AX
    LEA DX,MESSAGE2
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    XOR DX,DX
    CALL READ
    MOV SIDETWO,AX
    MOV DECIMALPOINTTWO,CL
    XOR DX,DX
    XOR AX,AX
    LEA DX,MESSAGE3
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    XOR DX,DX
    CALL READ
    MOV SIDETHREE,AX
    MOV DECIMALPOINTTHREE,CL
    XOR DX,DX
    XOR AX,AX
    LEA DX,RESULTMESSAGE
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    XOR DX,DX
    ;MOV DX,RESULT
    ;MOV AH,09H
    ;INT 21H
    ;XOR DX,DX
    XOR AX,AX
    MOV DX,OFFSET CONTINUEMESSAGE
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    MOV AH,01H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,79H
    JZ START
    CMP AL,6EH
    JZ FINISHPROGRAM

FINISHPROGRAM:
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    RET
MAIN ENDP
CODE ENDS
END MAIN
```

Comment: What did you discover when you tried debugging the program?

Comment: Everything goes well until the called procedure finishes it's job, but then simply does not return to my main function to continue the instructions. Goes onwards on memory and executes those random instruction which fill the memory.

Comment: You need to say this in your question rather than making people ask for it. Fortunately, the RET instruction is very simple. Look at the stack at the point of the RET to see what you are returning to. In other words, pay closer attention when debugging. Don't just step through the code. Look at what the instructions are doing.

Comment: It should jump to cs:003D back, but it jumps to cs:0000 and because there were some already done instructions now those lines in the memory are filled with random ones. Is this normal?

Comment: Good, now you know why the RET is going to the wrong place. Now you can figure out why the memory was not set properly. Hint: Look at your PUSH instructions.

Comment: Do I need to POP those data segment initializations first? (I don't exactly know why we use them, we weren't thought properly. Just the way: "use it all the time because only this way you can store the data elements or with other words your variables in the registers.")

Comment: Think about what happens if you don't POP them.

Comment: Awesome. You were right, return was going in the wrong place because there were remaining things on the stack. Thanks for this proper help, not just throwing an answer and a happy new year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is were you smashed the stack. Right at the beginning of your `READ` procedure:

```
PUSH DS
XOR AX,AX
PUSH AX
```

This sequence is needed at the beginning of an EXE program in order to finish it with a `RET FAR` instruction (an old way to terminate an EXE file btw) but it's NOT needed in any the procedures your program calls to. Delete it.

Also, as long as `DS` is not updated at any point in your program, you only need the sequence `MOV AX,DATA` / `MOV DS,AX` once, at the beginning of your program, not on every procedure.

You can effectively avoid the said sequence if you terminate your program this way:

```
MOV AX,4C00h
INT 21h
```

Which is the proper way to terminate a DOS process. The old way is by using `INT 20h`, but `INT 20h` needs `CS` to point to the `PSP` of the program, hence the `PUSH DS / XOR AX,AX / PUSH AX` sequence: a `RET FAR` instruction will load `CS:IP` with value `DS:0000h` continuing the execution at the beginning of the `PSP` in which an `INT 20h` instruction is placed by the `DOS` loader (an old remembrance of what once was the `CALL 0` or `RST 0` sequence to terminate a program in `CP/M` )